# Drawing signature in ipad app and convert it in image

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview

I am drawing signature in ipad app it works fine but problem is that when it saves image it also saves the border of the signatureView I want to save only the drawing area not complete signatureView here is my code

```
  signatureView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,800,500)];
signatureView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:242.0/255.f green:242/255.0f blue:242/255.0f alpha:1];


signatureView.layer.borderWidth =4;
signatureView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:23.0/255.0f green:190/255.0f blue:210/255.0f alpha:1].CGColor;
signatureView.layer.cornerRadius=30;




[self.view addSubview:signatureView];



UIButton*OkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [OkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(320,448,118,49)];
    [OkButton setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[OkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"okT.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


   [OkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onOKButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[signatureView addSubview:OkButton];

UILabel*textLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,6,300,50)];

textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16];
textLabel.text=@"Use the touchscreen to sign here";
textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
textLabel.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];    
[signatureView addSubview:textLabel];


    drawScreen=[[MyLineDrawingView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,50,780,400)];
    [signatureView addSubview:drawScreen];
    [drawScreen release];


    //MyLineDrwaingView


   @interface MyLineDrawingView : UIView {

    UIBezierPath *myPath;
    UIColor *brushPattern;
   }

  @end


    #import "MyLineDrawingView.h"


    @implementation MyLineDrawingView

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
  {

   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    self.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    myPath.lineCapStyle=kCGLineCapRound;
    myPath.miterLimit=0;
    myPath.lineWidth=10;
    //brushPattern=[UIColor redColor];
    brushPattern=[UIColor blackColor];

         }
        return self;
     }


    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
   {

     [brushPattern setStroke];
     [myPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
     }

    #pragma mark - Touch Methods

   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {

   UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
   [myPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];

   }

  -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

  {

   UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
  [myPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
   [self setNeedsDisplay];

  }


 -(void)onOKButtonClick {
 CGRect rect = [drawScreen bounds];   //use your signature view's Rect means Frame;
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 [signatureView.layer renderInContext:context];   //this line is also important for you
 UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    signImageView.image = img;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SO topic has exactly the same problem (Drawing and saving of a signature on iOS): [iOS: How to convert the self-drawn content of an UIView to an image (widespread general solution returns blank image)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229852/ios-how-to-convert-the-self-drawn-content-of-an-uiview-to-an-image-widespread)

Please try and mark your question solved, if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented in my code its work for me follow :

.h file add the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

.m fiel

```
-(void)scrollGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationInView:scrollView];

    NSLog(@"%d %d %d %d",touchLocation.y > signatureViewOne.frame.origin.y,touchLocation.y < signatureViewOne.frame.origin.y+80,touchLocation.x > 3, touchLocation.x < 308);
    if ((touchLocation.y > signatureViewOne.frame.origin.y && touchLocation.y < signatureViewOne.frame.origin.y+80) &&(touchLocation.x > 3 && touchLocation.x < 308))
    {
        NSLog(@"Signone found");
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    }
    else

    if ((touchLocation.y > signatureViewTwo.frame.origin.y && touchLocation.y < signatureViewTwo.frame.origin.y+80) &&(touchLocation.x > 3 && touchLocation.x < 308))
    {
        NSLog(@"SignTwo found");
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"not found");
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        sender.enabled = YES;
    }


}
```